# Start, Stop and Restart TimerTask with two buttons

Tags: android

I want to use a Button and TimerTask to start calling the method getCurrentLocation() in a regular intervall of 5 seconds. This works fine with the following code:

```
        final Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_startTimer);
        c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Timer t =new Timer();
                t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getCurrentLocation();
                    }
                }, 0, 5000);
            }
        });
```

Then I've got a second button (bt_stopTimer) which I wanted to use to stop calling the method regularly. If I press the start button (bt_startTimer) again, it should again start calling the method regularly and so on...
Where can I put in the stop button so it works? I tried this below the first code:

```
        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_stopTimer);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.cancel();
            }
        });
```

But of course the variable t is not defined here. Can anyone help? If it's possible with one start/stop button it would also be great but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should move " final Timer t =new Timer();" out of onClick method.

Example:

```
class MainActivity {

 final Timer t =new Timer();

  void onCreate() {
       final Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_startTimer);
        c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               
                t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getCurrentLocation();
                    }
                }, 0, 5000);
            }
        });

       final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_stopTimer);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t.cancel();
            }
        });

  }

}
```

Comment: This works almost fine but the app seems to crash when restarting the timer after a stop.

Comment: What is the crash stack?

Comment: This is the logcat of the Crash: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.currentlocation, PID: 5275
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
        at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:397) and a few more line all following the Timer canceled problem (they all start with "at")

Comment: I probably have to add the line "final Timer t =new Timer();" into the startbutton OnClickListener  again but only if the timer was cancelled before - just a guess... simply adding it into the stopTimer Listener after "t.cancel()" to reset the Timer does not work